# How to convert LF to CR/LF using Scripting.FileSystemObject and TextStream?

Tags: javascript, jscript, filesystemobject

I have a text file that contains "unix style" line endings: a 0x0A at the end of each line.

I'm writing a script to modify that file, to add new content to it. This is JScript, running on Windows. The code looks like this:

```
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"),
        fs = fso.openTextFile(src),
        origContent = fs.readAll();
    fs.Close();
    fso.MoveFile(src, dest);

    // write updated content to a new file.
    fs = fso.CreateTextFile(src);
    fs.WriteLine("# key: " + keyvaluee);
    fs.WriteLine("# group: " + groupvalue);
    fs.WriteLine(origContent);
    fs.Close();
```

The content of the resulting modified file is like this:

```
00000000: 2320 6b65 793a 2075 6e64 6566 696e 6564  # key: undefined
00000010: 0d0a 2320 6772 6f75 703a 2069 6d61 700d  ..# group: imap.
00000020: 0a23 636f 6e74 7269 6275 746f 7220 3a20  .#contributor : 
00000030: 416e 6472 6577 2047 776f 7a64 7a69 6577  Andrew Gwozdziew
00000040: 7963 7a20 3c77 6562 4061 7067 776f 7a2e  ycz <web@apgwoz.
00000050: 636f 6d3e 0a23 6e61 6d65 203a 2069 6d61  com>.#name : ima
00000060: 705f 6765 745f 7175 6f74 6172 6f6f 7428  p_get_quotaroot(
00000070: 2e2e 2e2c 202e 2e2e 290a 2320 2d2d 0a69  ..., ...).# --.i
00000080: 6d61 705f 6765 745f 7175 6f74 6172 6f6f  map_get_quotaroo
00000090: 7428 247b 696d 6170 5f73 7472 6561 6d7d  t(${imap_stream}
000000a0: 2c20 247b 7175 6f74 615f 726f 6f74 7d29  , ${quota_root})
000000b0: 2430 0d0a                                $0..
```

As you can see, the lines added with the JScript TextStream end in `0D 0A`, while the existing content ends each line in simply `0A`.  See the sequence at position 0x10 and compare to the byte at position 0x54. This is a text file, I'm just showing the content in hex.

How can I make the line endings consistent in the modified file? Either way is fine with me, I just don't like using both in the same file.

Can I convert the `origContent` string in memory to use "DOS style" line endings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just used a string replace with hex encoding. This worked for me.

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"),  
    fs = fso.openTextFile(src),  
    origContent = fs.readAll(),  
    re1 = new RegExp("\x0A", 'g');

fs.Close();  
fso.MoveFile(src, dest);  

// write updated content to a new file.  
fs = fso.CreateTextFile(src);  
fs.WriteLine("# key: " + keyvaluee);  
fs.WriteLine("# group: " + groupvalue); 
origContent = origContent.replace(re1, "\x0D\x0A");
fs.WriteLine(origContent);  
fs.Close();
```

The result is that all the line-endings in `origContent` get converted to CR/LF rather than just LF. 
This works only if there are *no CRLF pairs in the original file* - only if it had all unix line endings, originally.

Comment: BTW, you can use `\r` for `\x0d` (CR) and `\n` for `\x0a` (LF).

Comment: In order to work with files that have CR/LF pairs already, you can first replace all the CR/LF pairs to LF, then replace LF with CR/LF.